# Find all skipped numbers per group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this column in my table and I want to get all skipped transactions (which is a varchar)

- SA1
- SA3
- SA50
- SA999

I'm trying to get

- SA2
- SA4 to SA49
- SA51 to SA998

EDIT: I've checked the actual data, found out that it's non-trailing zeroes.

I've done this with PHP. Was wondering if is there a way within SQL to do it?

This might sound dumb, but what I'm trying is to plot it like this (this returns null values)

```
WITH cte (id) AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
    FROM sys.all_columns AS s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns AS s2
),
table1 AS (
    SELECT sNumber as id1 FROM Sales WHERE sNumber LIKE '%SI_'
),
table2 AS (
    SELECT sNumber as id1 FROM Sales WHERE sNumber LIKE '%SI__'
),
table3 AS (
    SELECT sNumber as id1 FROM Sales WHERE sNumber LIKE '%SI___'
)

SELECT
    'SA' + RIGHT('' + CAST(t1.id AS VARCHAR(2)), 1) AS id_missing
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t2
    ON t1.id = CAST(RIGHT(t2.id1, 1) AS INT)
WHERE
    t1.id < (SELECT MAX(CAST(RIGHT(id1, 1) AS INT)) FROM yourTable1) AND
    t2.id1 IS NULL
UNION ALL

SELECT
    'SA' + RIGHT('' + CAST(t1.id AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) AS id_missing
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.id = CAST(RIGHT(t2.id2, 2) AS INT)
WHERE
    t1.id < (SELECT MAX(CAST(RIGHT(id2, 2) AS INT)) FROM yourTable2) AND
    t2.id2 IS NULL
UNION ALL

SELECT
    'SA' + RIGHT('' + CAST(t1.id AS VARCHAR(3)), 3) AS id_missing
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN table3 t2
    ON t1.id = CAST(RIGHT(t2.id3, 3) AS INT)
WHERE
    t1.id < (SELECT MAX(CAST(RIGHT(id3, 3) AS INT)) FROM yourTable3) AND
    t2.id3 IS NULL
```

Comment: Yes. Do you have another question about using a _numbers_ (or _tally_) table to supply the missing values? You can use `Cast( Right( YourColumnOData, 3 ) as Int )` to get the existing numeric values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a calendar table approach with a left join here:

```
WITH cte (id) AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
    FROM sys.all_columns AS s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns AS s2
)

SELECT
    'SA' + RIGHT('000' + CAST(t1.id AS VARCHAR(3)), 3) AS id_missing
FROM cte t1
LEFT JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t1.id = CAST(RIGHT(t2.id, 3) AS INT)
WHERE
    t1.id < (SELECT MAX(CAST(RIGHT(id, 3) AS INT)) FROM yourTable) AND
    t2.id IS NULL;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

The idea is to generate a sequence of numbers covering the possible up to 1000 values which might appear in your current table as `SAxxx`.  Then, we left join this *calendar* table to your current table, on the condition that the numeric portion of the id does *not* match.  All such non matching `SAxxx` values are then retained in the result set.

Comment: If my transactions reaches to the thousand mark, how can I increase the cast and right number count while the data between 1 to 999 is retained?

Comment: Ideally, your `Sxxx` values should always have the same number of zeroes.  Is this the case?

Comment: Not exactly. I missed out the actual data that I'm checking doesn't have leading zeroes. They go as SA1, SA100, or SA1000.

Comment: @iamlux20 [Here is a demo with the updated logic you want](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a9765ea17c8a4e6ad3d8c67215244826).  I won't edit my above answer, since it in fact does answer the question you actually asked.